# My application crash without errors, Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

The application is an ordinary calculator, but there are tabs (ViewPager) on top. There are no errors in the code, but when you start the application, it immediately crashes, both on the emulator built into Android Studio and on your own phone. Restarting does not help. Invalidate caches / Restart too. Who is not new to Android Studio, please tell me where I made a mistake.

LOGCAT

```
2019-11-10 13:13:40.348 6986-6986/? I/ample.viewpage: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2019-11-10 13:13:40.401 6986-6986/? W/ample.viewpage: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2019-11-10 13:13:41.080 6986-6986/com.example.viewpager W/ample.viewpage: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;->getOpticalInsets()Landroid/graphics/Insets; (light greylist, linking)
2019-11-10 13:13:41.080 6986-6986/com.example.viewpager W/ample.viewpage: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->left:I (light greylist, linking)
2019-11-10 13:13:41.080 6986-6986/com.example.viewpager W/ample.viewpage: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->right:I (light greylist, linking)
2019-11-10 13:13:41.080 6986-6986/com.example.viewpager W/ample.viewpage: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->top:I (light greylist, linking)
2019-11-10 13:13:41.081 6986-6986/com.example.viewpager W/ample.viewpage: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->bottom:I (light greylist, linking)
2019-11-10 13:13:41.170 6986-6986/com.example.viewpager W/ample.viewpage: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
2019-11-10 13:13:41.171 6986-6986/com.example.viewpager W/ample.viewpage: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
2019-11-10 13:13:41.234 6986-6986/com.example.viewpager D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2019-11-10 13:13:41.238 6986-6986/com.example.viewpager E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.viewpager, PID: 6986
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.viewpager/com.example.viewpager.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.viewpager.MainActivity.setOnclick(MainActivity.java:119)
        at com.example.viewpager.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:55)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.viewpager;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import net.objecthunter.exp4j.Expression;
import net.objecthunter.exp4j.ExpressionBuilder;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Tab1.OnFragmentInteractionListener, Tab2.OnFragmentInteractionListener, Tab3.OnFragmentInteractionListener, View.OnClickListener {
    private EditText inputtext;
    private TextView resulttext;
    private Button but0;
    private Button but1;
    private Button but2;
    private Button but3;
    private Button but4;
    private Button but5;
    private Button but6;
    private Button but7;
    private Button but8;
    private Button but9;
    private ImageButton butadd;
    private ImageButton butmin;
    private ImageButton butmulti;
    private Button butdivi;
    private ImageButton butdelet;
    private Button butc;
    private Button butbra;
    private Button but100;
    private Button butequl;
    private Button butsing;
    private Button butvir;
    private boolean stateError;
    private boolean isNumber;
    private boolean lastDot;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        inisializeButtons();
        setOnclick();
        // Hiding and disable keyboard
        inputtext.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);

        inputtext.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 3"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
        {

        }

    }
    private void inisializeButtons() {
        this.inputtext = findViewById(R.id.input);
        this.resulttext = findViewById(R.id.result);
        this.but0 = findViewById(R.id.but0);
        this.but1 = findViewById(R.id.but1);
        this.but2 = findViewById(R.id.but2);
        this.but3 = findViewById(R.id.but3);
        this.but4 = findViewById(R.id.but4);
        this.but5 = findViewById(R.id.but5);
        this.but6 = findViewById(R.id.but6);
        this.but7 = findViewById(R.id.but7);
        this.but8 = findViewById(R.id.but8);
        this.but9 = findViewById(R.id.but9);
        this.but100 = findViewById(R.id.but100);
        this.butadd = findViewById(R.id.butplus);
        this.butmin = findViewById(R.id.butmin);
        this.butmulti = findViewById(R.id.butmult);
        this.butdivi = findViewById(R.id.butdivi);
        this.butdelet = findViewById(R.id.butdelet);
        this.butbra = findViewById(R.id.butbra);
        this.butsing = findViewById(R.id.butsin);
        this.butc = findViewById(R.id.butc);
        this.butequl = findViewById(R.id.butequl);
        this.butvir = findViewById(R.id.butv);

    }
    private void setOnclick() {
        this.but0.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.but1.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.but2.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.but3.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.but4.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.but5.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.but6.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.but7.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.but8.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.but9.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.but100.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.butadd.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.butmulti.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.butmin.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.butdelet.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.butdivi.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.butvir.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.butequl.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.butc.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.butdelet.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.butsing.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.butbra.setOnClickListener(this);


    }
    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int Id = v.getId();
        switch (Id) {
            case R.id.but0:
                append("0");
                isNumber = true;
                break;
            case R.id.but1:
                append("1");
                isNumber = true;
                break;
            case R.id.but2:
                append("2");
                isNumber = true;
                break;
            case R.id.but3:
                append("3");
                isNumber = true;
                break;
            case R.id.but4:
                append("4");
                isNumber = true;
                break;
            case R.id.but5:
                append("5");
                isNumber = true;
                break;
            case R.id.but6:
                append("6");
                isNumber = true;
                break;
            case R.id.but7:
                append("7");
                isNumber = true;
                break;
            case R.id.but8:
                append("8");
                isNumber = true;
                break;
            case R.id.but9:
                append("9");
                isNumber = true;
                break;
            case R.id.but100:
                if (!isEmpty() && isNumber)
                    append("%");
                break;
            case R.id.butplus:
                if (!isEmpty())
                    if (endsWithOperatore())
                        replace("+");
                    else
                        append("+");
                isNumber = false;
                lastDot = false;
                break;
            case R.id.butmin:
                if (endsWithOperatore())
                    replace("-");
                else
                    append("-");
                isNumber = false;
                lastDot = false;
                break;
            case R.id.butmult:
                if (!isEmpty())
                    if (endsWithOperatore())
                        replace("x");
                    else
                        append("x");
                isNumber = false;
                lastDot = false;
                break;
            case R.id.butdivi:
                if (!isEmpty())
                    if (endsWithOperatore())
                        replace("/");
                    else
                        append("/");
                isNumber = false;
                lastDot = false;
                break;
            case R.id.butv:
                if (isNumber && !stateError && !lastDot) {
                    append(".");
                    isNumber = false;
                    lastDot = true;
                } else if (isEmpty()) {
                    append("0.");
                    isNumber = false;
                    lastDot = true;
                }
                break;
            case R.id.butdelet:
                delete();
                break;
            case R.id.butc:
                clear();
                break;
            case R.id.butbra:
                bracket();
                break;
            case R.id.butequl:
                calcule(true);
                break;
            case R.id.butsin:
                setSing();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }
    private void setSing() {
        if (isEmpty()){
            append("(-");
        }else if (isNumber && !endsWithOperatore()){
            int index1;
            int index2;
            int index3;
            int index4;
            int lastone = 0;
            index1 = getinput().lastIndexOf("x") + 1;
            index2 = getinput().lastIndexOf("+") + 1;
            index3 = getinput().lastIndexOf("-") + 1;
            index4 = getinput().lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
            if (index1 > index2 && index1 > index3 && index1 > index4)
                lastone = index1;
            else if (index2 > index1 && index2 > index3 && index2 > index4)
                lastone = index2;
            else if (index3 > index2 && index3 > index1 && index3 > index4)
                lastone = index1;
            else if (index4 > index1 && index4 > index3 && index4 > index2)
                lastone = index1;
            char ch=getinput().charAt(lastone);
            appendsing("(-" + String.valueOf(ch), lastone);

        }
    }

    private void appendsing(String str,int index) {

        inputtext.getText().replace(index,index+1,str);
    }


    private void bracket() {
        if ((!stateError && !isEmpty() && !endsWithbra() && isNumber) || isclosed()) {
            append("x(");
        } else if (isEmpty() || endsWithOperatore() || endsWithbra()) {
            append("(");
        } else if (!isEmpty() && !endsWithbra()) {
            append(")");
        }
    }

    private boolean endsWithbra() {
        return getinput().endsWith("(");
    }

    private boolean isclosed() {
        return getinput().endsWith(")");
    }

    private boolean endsWithOperatore() {
        return getinput().endsWith("+") || getinput().endsWith("-") || getinput().endsWith("/") || getinput().endsWith("x");
    }

    private void replace(String str) {
        inputtext.getText().replace(getinput().length() - 1, getinput().length(), str);
    }

    private void clear() {
        lastDot = false;
        isNumber = false;
        stateError = false;
        inputtext.getText().clear();
    }

    private void append(String str) {
        this.inputtext.getText().append(str);
    }

    private void delete() {
        if (!isEmpty()) {
            this.inputtext.getText().delete(getinput().length() - 1, getinput().length());

        } else clear();
    }

    private String getinput() {
        return this.inputtext.getText().toString();
    }

    private boolean isEmpty() {
        return getinput().isEmpty();
    }

    private void calcule(boolean isequlclick) {

        String input = getinput();
        try {
            if (!isEmpty() && !endsWithOperatore()) {
                if (input.contains("x")) {
                    input = input.replaceAll("x", "*");
                }
                Expression expression = new ExpressionBuilder(input).build();
                double result = expression.evaluate();
                if (isequlclick) {
                    inputtext.setText(String.valueOf(result));
                    resulttext.setText("");
                } else
                    resulttext.setText(String.valueOf(result));
            } else resulttext.setText("");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            stateError = true;
            isNumber = false;
        }

    }

    TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            calcule(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    };
}
```

Comment: post your xml file plz

Answer (score 2):

Your application does crash with an error. You are receiving a NullPointerException. `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference`

This means you are setting an OnClickListener on a Button that is null. In your `initializeButtons()` procedure you may have forgotten a Button or misspelled the ID?

Comment: I would try to comment out the `initializeButtons()`procedure and comment out the `setOnClick()`procedure and test with one button in your MainActivity directly. So comment out those two procedures and add to your MainActivity just for testing this: `but0 = findViewById(R.id.but0);` and `but0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 Log.d("TESTING", "But0 works");
             }
         });`

Comment: Maybe check out this video and take a closer look at where the Buttons are defined and where you need to invoke the `setOnClickListener(this)`. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GtxVILjLcw8